# Add conditional filter before applying limitTo

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I use limitTo along with a conditional? The documentation of it shows only simple usage.

Say I want to display 2 results of items named car:

```
$scope.items = [
    {"name":"laptop","color":"green"},
    {"name":"shoe","color":"blue"},
    {"name":"Car","color":"gold"},
    {"name":"Car","color":"gold"},
    {"name":"Car","color":"gold"}
];
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/E3ePEmBBxetaatVRpB6s?p=preview)

Comment: what do you mean by conditional? your sentence doesnt make sense.

Answer (score 1):

You can prepend an additional filter to your `limitTo` filter. This is known as filter chaining:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: 'car' | limitTo: 2">{{item.name}}</li>
```

If you'd like for `filter` to apply to only your items array's name property, you can use an object literal to narrow it down:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {name: 'car'} | limitTo: 2">{{item.name}} - {{item.color}}</li>
```

This can also use a dynamic value based on user input:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="search.name" />
<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: search | limitTo: 2">{{item.name}} - {{item.color}}</li>
```

Read more about [filter chaining](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter) in the Angular docs.

Comment: your second block of code name:'car', can I do the reverse? like name contain !car

Comment: `<li ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {name: '!car'} | limitTo: 2">{{item.name}}</li>` http://plnkr.co/edit/YRHLCx54zGp7otzm9U7n?p=preview

Comment: I see you opened another question... Did my answer for this one sufficiently address what you asked here?